# ASP.NET application crashes when CPU configuration is changed from AnyCPU to x86

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, build

I have an ASP.Net application with 2 modules:

1. A server module, runs as a windows service.
2. A web module installed on IIS.

The above works perfectly (have been working) for last several years. Problem has just happened when I have to move the application to a new windows 2008 server.

What I have done is:

1. Changed the target from AnyCPU to x86 on server module, then tested it
   on an BP machine and everything worked.
2. Moved the server and web module to Win 2008 server.
3. Installed the service and ran it, so far so good.
4. From the web site, I ran a query which failed with a null pointer
   exception and something like this:

> at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)

This is where my head started spinning. My code to talk to service is similar to this:

```
<application name="SHR">
    <client url="tcp://localhost:8039">
        <wellknown type="Package.dal.MyDAO, MyPackage" url="tcp://localhost:8039/SHR/MyDAO.rem"/>           
    </client>
    <channels>
        <channel ref="tcp client">
            <clientProviders>
                <formatter ref="binary" includeVersions="false"/>
                <provider type="server, server"/>
            </clientProviders>
        </channel>
    </channels>
</application>
```

I ran sql profiler and I can see the the class method that I am trying to call does execute completely, but for some reasons, it doesn't return anything. The class itself instantiates correctly as well as I have ran queries where I insert/delete and everything works, but when I need a dataset returned, it returns null even though I know its not null).

The issue occurs only in Win 2008 when I change the CPU to x86. I get another set of errors if I try to run the service without changing AnyCPU to x86.

Comment: Please come up with a better title for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the web.config to the new IIS? It could be just a max size message mismatch between server and client

Comment: Yes, I have, as I mentioned, the web site works as long as I dont trigger that one part where it references that particular class

Comment: Can you attach the full exception stack?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here it is, It turned out to be a database user permission. The problem was that the error that I was getting from .net framework was absolutely crap and had no pointer that it was because of some type of user permissions. Thanks for every one who tried.